# Python 2 vs 3. Same inputs, different results. MD5 hash

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, md5

Python 3 code:

```
def md5hex(data):
    """ return hex string of md5 of the given string """
    h = MD5.new()
    h.update(data.encode('utf-8'))
    return b2a_hex(h.digest()).decode('utf-8')
```

Python 2 code:

```
def md5hex(data):
    """ return hex string of md5 of the given string """
    h = MD5.new()
    h.update(data)
    return b2a_hex(h.digest())
```

Input python 3:

```
>>> md5hex('bf5¤7¤8¤3')
'61d91bafe643c282bd7d7af7083c14d6'
```

Input python 2:

```
>>> md5hex('bf5¤7¤8¤3')
'46440745dd89d0211de4a72c7cea3720'
```

Whats going on?

EDIT:

```
def genurlkey(songid, md5origin, mediaver=4, fmt=1):
    """ Calculate the deezer download url given the songid, origin and media+format """
    data = b'\xa4'.join(_.encode("utf-8") for _ in [md5origin, str(fmt), str(songid), str(mediaver)])
    data = b'\xa4'.join([md5hex(data), data])+b'\xa4'
    if len(data)%16:
        data += b'\x00' * (16-len(data)%16)
    return hexaescrypt(data, "jo6aey6haid2Teih").decode('utf-8')
```

All this problem started with this b'\xa4' in python 2 code in another function. This byte doesn't work in python 3.

And with that one I get the correct MD5 hash...

Comment: Have you tried using a `u` prefixed string?

Comment: @NilsWerner, yes. Same result.

Comment: Did you try with `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ?

Comment: using \x notation I get same checksum for all: `h=md5("bf5\xc2\xa47\xc2\xa48\xc2\xa43"); h.hexdigest() => 61d91....`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The problem is that in python 2 code, its b'\xa4', and it doesn't work in python 3.

Comment: `b'\xa4'.join(...` makes no sense because `b'\xa4'` isn't a valid utf-8 encoded sequence. All utf-8 values above 0x7f are at least two bytes in length. A problem with python 2 is a string print goes through the local console which will decode it but it can still be funky inside. Are you running on windows? These could be Windows codepage values and not unicode at all. When I copy/paste to my linux utf-8 console, I get thet same on python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Gribouillis, I did not. I'll search about it, thanks

Comment: Can you update your short examples to something that actually works ( eg, where did you get `MD5.new()` from?). And in the function, include `print(repr(data))` so we know what it really looks like.

Comment: @tdelaney, yes, Im on Windows. And it works fine with `b'\xa4'`. If I do: `print (b'\xa4')` it prints the '¤' character

Comment: @tdelaney, http://pastebin.com/FkNb0GEr this is the original code which works fine in python 2 but don't in 3

Comment: There's your problem. The join is only working by luck... my bet is that all of your data is in the ascii range so you don't notice you've mismatched encodings. As a minimum you could try `u'¤'.join(unicode(val)for val in [md5origin, fmt, songid, mediaver]).encode('utf-8')` but if this is a bunch of code mixing utf-8 and codepage encodings in a python 2 `str` object... well I think that was one of Dante's levels of hell.

Comment: @tdelaney, simpler than that, my friend. It was just about encoding type.. take a look on TemporalWolfs answer. He solved the problem ;)

Comment: That's how I did it on my linux box also... but I was stuck on what that means for codepage verses utf-8 encodings. I don't have windows so had to guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) & a language agnostic implementation instead:

```
import hashlib
text = u'bf5¤7¤8¤3'
text = text.encode('utf-8')
print(hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest())
```

works in Python 2/3 with the same result:

Python2:

```
'61d91bafe643c282bd7d7af7083c14d6'
```

Python3 (via repl.it):

```
'61d91bafe643c282bd7d7af7083c14d6'
```

The reason your code is failing is the encoded string is **not** the same string as the un-encoded one: You are only encoding for Python 3.

---

If you need it to match the unencoded Python 2:

```
import hashlib
text = u'bf5¤7¤8¤3'
print(hashlib.md5(text.encode("latin1")).hexdigest())
```

works:

```
46440745dd89d0211de4a72c7cea3720
```

the default encoding for Python 2 is `latin1` not `utf-8`

Comment: I edited my question with the problem which generates the '¤' character. The correct result should be '46440745dd89d0211de4a72c7cea3720'.

Comment: @EduardoM is there some reason that is the 'correct' result? The hash value should be irrelevant as long as both give the same result for the same input.

Comment: Its because the original code is in python 2. I declared the encode because the code was returning a KeyError `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`
In python 2, the correct one, its not necessary to encode.

Comment: @EduardoM Because what you want to do is unsupported in Python 3.

Comment: Should be some workaround there... is this impossible to get the correct hash in python 3?

Comment: +1. 'xyz123' pulled off a JSON request is not equal to python string 'xyz123'. Had to do str() to make sure hashes are same

Comment: @Fakeer in python 2 or 3? It's almost certainly an encoding issue, which `str()` should address, as you found.

Answer (score 1):

Default encoding in python3 is Unicode. In python 2 it's ASCII. So even if string matches when read they are presented differently.

Comment: Is there any solution? I need the same result that I get in python 2 code. The problem is the '¤' character.

Comment: Have you declared encoding in python2 sources?

Comment: I just put it in python 3 source because the code gives a TypeError: `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: Try to put this after #/usr/bin/python or something like it (after first line)
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
Then save file as utf-8.
Then check if there is difference between two of them :)

Comment: The problem was just about encoding type. It is latin1 instead utf-8. 
Thanks anyway