# hashlib python2 vs python3

Tags: python, hashlib

Hint: all variables are strings. and im using the hashlib lib

```
from hashlib import sha256, md5
S2_SRP_MAGIC1 = "[!~esTo0}"
S2_SRP_MAGIC2 = "taquzaph_?98phab&junaj=z=kuChusu"
S2_SALT2 = "p^^^&bjRlXi4B=A1y.@Vz)"
password = "asd"
```

this line worked fine in python 2:

```
p = sha256(md5(md5(password + S2_SALT2 + S2_SRP_MAGIC1) + S2_SRP_MAGIC2))
```

When i port this line to python3 the response is:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I did a little research and modified the line so it wont give me any errors, but im not sure if i did it correct, because the srp auth isnt working.
my new line:

```
p = sha256((md5((md5(password.encode()).hexdigest() + S2_SALT2 + S2_SRP_MAGIC1).encode()).hexdigest() + S2_SRP_MAGIC2).encode()).hexdigest()
```

Is that completly wrong or is it correct?

Comment: Please share an example of a `password`, `S2_SALT2`, `S2_SRP_MAGIC1` and `S2_SRP_MAGIC2` value that shows this problem, or at least share code of how you construct them. The issue here will be about the data type of these values. (the code defining them from your Python 2 script might help)

Comment: That .hexdigest() part is almost certainly wrong. Sorry, too tired for a full answer.

Comment: I’m not sure how `md5(…) + …` worked in Python 2 – the docs aren’t clear – but try `digest` instead of `hexdigest`.

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068617/python-2-vs-3-same-inputs-different-results-md5-hash

Comment: variables updated

Comment: When I run your code in py2 I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hash.py", line 9, in <module>
    p = sha256(md5(md5(password + S2_SALT2 + S2_SRP_MAGIC1) + S2_SRP_MAGIC2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_hashlib.HASH' and 'str'